# Java code for generating Excel report with formula for cells

Tags: java

How can I use this Excel formula

```
IF(W2<>"",NETWORKDAYS(V2,W2),"")
```

in Java to generate an Excel report?

Answer (score 2):

Try [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) which reads/writes MS Office files.  Check out the POI support for writing [Excel formulas](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/formula.html).

Comment: IF i use setformula() for the IF(W2<>"",NETWORKDAYS(V2,W2),"")  it get realigned to wrong order.. please suggest the right to generate excel..

Answer (score 0):

You can also Try JXL api.

**http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/**